# Python reads CSV on OS X differently then Windows?

Tags: python, csv

I have a Python script that writes and reads multiple CSV files. On OS X, in order to perform any calculations on any values in the CSV file, I have to float the value `float(d['var_returns'])`. This works perfectly fine on OS X and the entire script works as performed.

However, using the exact same code on Windows, I get:

`ValueError: could not convert string to float: var_returns`

I was wondering why this is happening, and how I can fix it? The typical value in var_returns would be `0.050244079`

Comment: Check your windows settings: what number separator are you using?

Comment: You'll have to show more details. Can you reproduce the issue with some sample code? The only difference between Windows and OS X file handling is going to be in the line endings, make sure you open your files according to the guidelines in the `csv` module documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was just a problem in the csv file. What happened was that I was running the same file, which caused another header row to be entered. When there is more then one header row, the script tries to convert something like "ind_sharpe" into a float which obviously will not work, and breaks the program.

The solution, overwrite header rows, don't stack them.